# How to find my classes in decompiled apk with instant run feature?

Tags: java, android, class, apk, decompiler

I have deleted source code of my app, but I have apk. I opened it with Analyze APK, but I couldn't find my activity classes. I think it's because my app was created with instant run feature. There are four classes.dex files and they contains only com.android.tools.ir. How can I find my classes?